# Does Cloud Search API require cloud search to be signed up?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-cloud-search

I need to use Google Cloud Search API for using with non-google workspace data (third party data like PDF etc.)
Is it mandatory to sign up for cloud search to use cloud search API?

Right now don't have google workspace.
Getting following error after setting up following this in the initialize third party support part:https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/project-setup

{
"error": {
"code": 404,
"message": "Requested entity was not found.",
"status": "NOT_FOUND"
}
}

Comment: The short answer to this is `No`. You don't need to create a Google Workspace account if you'd like to use the `Cloud Search API` for `non-google workspace data`. One reason for the `Requested entity was not found.` happens when the credentials are incorrect. Can you tell us what you've tried to fix this so far? It'll help other community members give you better advice.